# Nodejs and microsoft bot framework

Tags: node.js

I am looking at the nodejs code here
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/basics-waterfall/app.js

I am trying to understand this piece of code

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
    function (session) {
        ...
    },
    function (session, results) {
        ...
    },
    function (session, results) {
       ...
    },
    function (session, results) {
        ...
    }
]);
```

I understand that 
var bot is a function expression and takes in two parameters one is a connector and another is an array of functions.

Do these array of functions execute serially in the order they are defined ?

Comming from another programming background i am not familiar with this dialect.

How can i make this program more C# like is async await the answer ?

If async await is the answer how do i convert this to use the async/await paradigm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems like they are executing in the order they are defined.

You are supposed to provide only the function body in that array, the actual execution happens somewhere in the bot implementation, so you'd have to look there to get a clearer picture.

But judging from that example and common sense, it's clear that they are executed sequentially. It's a bot that answers questions in the order they are defined.

I'm not sure what you understand by "async" in this context, but if you want it to answer arbitrary requests, you can look at the other examples like *basics-logging*.